# Sum of columns from two data frames that contain float values

Tags: python, pandas, addition

I have two data frames.
The columns name are the same of those data frames.
I want to sum the float values of the same columns from dataframes
Then I can use

```
df3 = df1.add(df2)
```

However, my dataframes contain two colums of  string. These strings are added too.
How can I wrtie the code not to add the string but to add the float in  two data frames
The two sample dataframes are as follow:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Team=['A','B','C','D'],Value=[1,2,3,4]),index=[0,1,2,3])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Team=['A','B','C','D'],Value=[3,1,2,4]),index=[0,1,2,3])
```

When I used `df3 = df1.add(df2)`
it also added the string in column "Team" as follow:

```
  Team  Value
0  AA     4
1  BB     3
2  CC     5
3  DD     8
```

How can I write code without adding the Team but the Value.

Thanks,

Zep

Comment: You are adding two 'dataframes', but what you want to do is to add two 'columns' from separate dataframes.  Just Google 'pandas sum two columns from different dataframes'. And you will find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the team names as indices instead of integer indices:

```
In [2]: df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Team=['A','B','C','D'],Value=[1,2,3,4])).set_index('Team')
   ...: df2 = pd.DataFrame(dict(Team=['A','B','C','D'],Value=[3,1,2,4])).set_index('Team')

In [3]: df1 + df2
Out[3]: 
      Value
Team       
A         4
B         3
C         5
D         8
```

In case you have multiple other columns, just sum the columns:

```
total = df1['Value'] + df2['Value']
```

If, in addition, you need a dataframe of the same shape as `df1` and `df2` with `Value` replaced by the sum, you can do

```
df3 = df1.copy()
df3['Value'] = total
```

Comment: If I hv multiple columns that contains string, should I set multi index?

Comment: @Zephyr No, in that case just sum your columns. I updated my answer.